# wxWidgets Windows->MacOS or Linux

Tags: c++, cross-platform, wxwidgets

I did a C++ code whose GUI is implemented with wxWidgets 3.1, and which I run on Windows. Being a cross-platform solution, I tried compiling the project on MacOS.
I'm running into several issues:

- wxWindow::SetDoubleBuffered does not seem to be implemented on MacOS (is-it also the case on Linux ?). I can go around and turn off double buffering at the expense of some flickering in my drawings for Mac users. That's not ideal: is-there something equivalent for Mac / Linux ?
- The constructor wxBitmap(const wxImage &image, const wxDC &dc) doesn't seem to exist either on MacOS. I use it to be able to use "dc.DrawBitmap" (combined with dc.SetUserScale) on a wxImage created from a C-style array of RGB triples. How do Mac users display pixel arrays on screen using wxWidgets ?
- Apparently there is no wxString to std::string conversion on MacOS (`no viable conversion from 'wxString' to 'std::string'` error). How is it even OS specific ?
- (minor detail) : `error: use of undeclared identifier 'sample_xpm' : SetIcon(wxICON(sample));` It seems sample_xpm is a default icon that is available on Windows and not MacOS.... (?).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: how did you build the library on OSX? I.e. what configure options did you pass? What OSX version are you trying the program on? Did you try to see if the problems persists in the drawing sample for the OSX? About the conversion - did you see https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Converting_everything_to_and_from_wxString? The icon - are you trying to use the sample's icon on your software?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be better to ask separate questions separately, as things risk getting confusing if we try discussing all them together, but here are the basic answers:

1. `wxWindow::SetDoubleBuffered()` is not provided in wxOSX because all windows are double-buffered there. A stub for it should still be arguably provided, for portability, but it will still do nothing and not calling it shouldn't result in any flickering.
2. wxBitmap ctor with this signature is not documented on purpose, it doesn't really make sense for the non-MSW platforms. Just use the ctor without the `dc` parameter instead.
3. Conversion from wxString to `std::string` is not OS-specific but depends on your build options: it is implicitly provided only if you build with `wxUSE_STL=1` set in your setup.h (or `--enable-stl` configure option). To avoid relying on this, you can always use `ToStdString()` explicitly. Or ensure that you build with the same options under all platforms.
4. This error is, presumably, in your own code and must be due to not including the XPM file. There is nothing platform-specific about this and you actually usually do *not* need XPMs under MSW so I'm not sure what you did there -- but just look at how and where do you include it.

Comment: Thanks for all! For the sample.xpm, it is a file present in the directory wxWidgets-3.1.0\samples ; on Windows (with visual studio) I didn't include this directory, but it found this icon anyway. Maybe the wxWidgets install on MacOS didn't contain the samples or didn't find the directory. This bug isn't really important, I was just wondering. Thanks again!